# Jupyter Notebook io.StringIO as output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bioinformatics, biopython, stringio

Input

```
Blast_aa_mc = qblast("blastp","nr", aa_mc[2])
Blast_aa_mc
```

Output

```
<_io.StringIO at 0x12a1a48>
```

What is _io.StringIO? and what does it mean? What I was expecting was some sort of string or array. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) is a class from Python's [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module in the standard library.
Essentially a StringIO object behaves like a Python file object that is not stored on disk but kept in memory.

Let's see a simple example:

```
f = io.StringIO("Some initial\ntext data.")
```

If you print it out, you get a result similar to yours:

```
print(f)

>> <_io.StringIO object at 0x7f4530264a68>
```

How to deal with this? Well, virtually anything that you can do with a file object, you can do with a StringIO object. For example to get the list of all lines in f:

```
    content = f.readlines()
    print(content)

    >> ['Some initial\n', 'text data.']
```

And to get a single string containing all content:

```
print(''.join(content))

>> 'Some initial
text data.'
```

Please note that you can only call readlines once - just as it is the case for files. The second call to readlines will return an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the results handle returned from `qblast()`via the `Bio.SearchIO` module, e.g.

```
from Bio import SearchIO
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW

Blast_aa_mc = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastp","nr", aa_mc[2])
blast_qresult = SearchIO.read(Blast_aa_mc, "blast-xml")
print(blast_qresult)
```

This is covered in my recent [Biopython Jupyter Notebook tutorial](https://github.com/chris-rands/biopython-coronavirus).

For multiple results use `SearchIO.parse(Blast_aa_mc, "blast-xml")` (wrap `list()` around it to create a list in memory)